# How to remove project from build path for sub-folders only

Tags: java, eclipse, compilation, classpath, buildpath

I have a `ProjectB` that's on the build path of `ProjectA`. However with `ProjectA` there are 5 sub-folders, each with 5 classes within them (some will be `Main`, some not).

My objective is to have `ProjectB` on the build path of `ProjectA` except for the build path of the classes within one of these folders.

How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You don't/can't, entries on the Java Build Path apply to the entire project. It sounds like you should have 5 separate `ProjectA`s, anyway.